# Как при промахе по TLB получить нужную PTE без обхода предыдущих уровней иерархии?

Tags: virtual, paging, x86-64

Рассматриваем расширении архитектуры x86-64, четырехуровневую иерархию страниц виртуальной памяти.

При промахе по TLB нужно будет провести дополнительные чтения из памяти (PLM4, PDP, PD).

Вопрос в том, как получить PTE без лишних обращений в память (либо их уменьшить)? Как оптимизировать процесс?
Вопрос теоретический.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решено.

В TLB помимо прямой трансляции виртуального адреса в физический адрес страницы, можно хранить указатели на таблицы страниц.

Таким образом, мы сможем сразу обратиться к PD и далее к физической странице, если указатель на нужную PD не найдем - можем обратиться к PDP и так далее (от младших битов).